# Reverse formula of altitude/pressure

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know there were questions like this before. I tried, but I'm not really good at math and the formula is quite difficult for me.

So formula is

$$hPa = \frac{101325(1-2.25577 \cdot10^{-5}\cdot Alt)^{5.25588}}{100}$$

where $Alt$ is altitude in meters. I need to find out the altitude knowing pressure in $hPa$. All the rest of the values are fixed.

Comment: Do you know that $$x = \frac{a}{100} \implies a = 100x$$ and $$y = x^{c}  \implies x = y^{1/c}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to write $h$ for $hPA$ and $A$ for alt. What you've got is
$$
\newcommand{lt}{\log_{10}}
h = (101325*(1-2.25577 * 10**-5 * A)**5.25588) / 100
$$
I'll transform that, a step at a time, to what you need. 
\begin{align}
h &= (101325*(1-2.25577 * 10**-5 * A)**5.25588) / 100 & \text{rewrite in math form}\\
h &= \frac{101325\cdot(1-2.25577 \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A)^{5.25588} }{100}\\
100h &= 101325\cdot(1-2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A)^{5.25588} \\
\frac{100h}{101345} &= (1-2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A)^{5.25588} \\
\lt(\frac{100h}{101345}) &= 5.25588 \lt(1-2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5} * A) \\
\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}  &= \lt(1-2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A) \\
10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}  &= 1-2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A \\
1 - 10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}  &= 2.25577  \cdot 10^{-5}  \cdot A \\
\frac{1 - 10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}}{ 10^{-5} \cdot  2.25577} &=  A \\
\end{align}

That can be slightly simplified:
\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1 - 10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}}{ 10^{-5} \cdot  2.25577}\\
A &= 10^5\frac{1 - 10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}}{ 2.25577}\\
A &\approx 0.44330760671 \cdot
10^5 \left( 1 - 10^\frac{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})}{5.25588}\right)\\
&= 0.44330760671 \cdot
10^5 \left( 1 - \left( 10^{\lt(\frac{100h}{101345})} \right)^{\frac{1}{5.25588}}\right)\\
&= 0.44330760671 \cdot
10^5 \left( 1 - \left( \frac{100h}{101345} \right)^{\frac{1}{5.25588}}\right)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation of the form
$$
y= A(1-Bx)^C
$$
where $A= \frac{101325}{100}$, $B=2.25577\times 10^{-5}$ and $C=5.25588$. Now we can do some algebra to solve for $x$. First divide both sides by $A$:
$$
\frac{y}{A} = (1-Bx)^C
$$
then take both sides to power $\frac{1}{C}$:
$$
\left(\frac{y}{A} \right)^{\frac{1}{C}} = 1- Bx
$$
... and maybe from this on you can continue?